# SearchEventListener is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed

Tags: java, swing, runtime, jbutton, actionlistener

At the moment I found one problem. I tried to add action (when I press the button, cmd.exe opened). This is my code (search is a button) And this problem appears only when I am tying to run application from my Java app (I tried make "if button pressed show message "success"):

```
public MainWindow (){
    super("SysAdminTool");
    this.setBounds(100, 100, 700 , 90);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    this.setResizable(false);

    Container container = this.getContentPane();
    container.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 2 , 1, 1));
    container.add(lcn);
    container.add(icn);

    container.add(lun);
    container.add(iun);

    container.add(empty);
    search.addActionListener(new SearchEventListener ());
    container.add(search);
}

    class SearchEventListener implements ActionListener {
        public void ActionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe");
        }
    }
}
```

Error:
Error:(38, 9) java:

```
sys.tool.MainWindow.SearchEventListener is not abstract and does 
    not override abstract method actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent) 
    in java.awt.event.ActionListener
```

Comment: See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void ActionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
```

You have a typo. Method names in Java should NOT start with an upper case character.

When you override a method you should use:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e){
```

Then you will get an error if your override the method incorrectly.